# Disable babel plugin on CircleCI

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, circleci

I'd like to disable/not install one specific npm package in my app when CircleCI runs its tests, because the package makes the build process fail.

To be specific, it is a babel plugin for react-intl that automatically parses the files and pulls strings in another folder (babel-plugin-react-intl).

What is the best way of achieving this? Can this be done in the .babelrc file for example?

Comment: why does it fail in circle CI ? How you install and run tests locally should be the same as your CI setup

Answer (score 1):

How you install and run tests locally should be the same as your CI setup.

If you need to disable a babel transform for tests - have them run as a different `NODE_ENV` and make sure your `.babelrc` only includes the plugin for the specific `NODE_ENV` 
eg:

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["react-intl"]
    }
  }
}
```

See: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option